# Docker is not running when trying to create a Laravel application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I am starting with Laravel and I am following the installation guide from the official [website](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#getting-started-on-linux).

So I had to install Docker with this [guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-convenience-script).

When I run the last command it works fine

`sudo docker run hello-world`

Then, following the guide on the Laravel site, I run the command:

`curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`

to create a Laravel application as it said.

But when I do so it doesn't work and this message appears:

`Docker is not running.`

The output of systemctl status docker

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-03-24 09:55:07 EDT; 6min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 1445 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 13
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─1445 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Mar 24 09:55:06 wrrnrtm-A320M-HD2 dockerd[1445]: time="2021-03-24T09:55:06.568086445-04:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support CPU realtime scheduler"
Mar 24 09:55:06 wrrnrtm-A320M-HD2 dockerd[1445]: time="2021-03-24T09:55:06.568093668-04:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight"
Mar 24 09:55:06 wrrnrtm-A320M-HD2 dockerd[1445]: time="2021-03-24T09:55:06.568100040-04:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device"
Mar 24 09:55:06 wrrnrtm-A320M-HD2 dockerd[1445]: time="2021-03-24T09:55:06.568236866-04:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Mar 24 09:55:07 wrrnrtm-A320M-HD2 dockerd[1445]: time="2021-03-24T09:55:07.227307787-04:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Mar 24 09:55:07 wrrnrtm-A320M-HD2 dockerd[1445]: time="2021-03-24T09:55:07.501565370-04:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Mar 24 09:55:07 wrrnrtm-A320M-HD2 dockerd[1445]: time="2021-03-24T09:55:07.551553136-04:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=363e9a8 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.5
Mar 24 09:55:07 wrrnrtm-A320M-HD2 dockerd[1445]: time="2021-03-24T09:55:07.551881250-04:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Mar 24 09:55:07 wrrnrtm-A320M-HD2 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 24 09:55:07 wrrnrtm-A320M-HD2 dockerd[1445]: time="2021-03-24T09:55:07.578162675-04:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
I'm using Xubuntu 18.04

Comment: You may want to edit your question and add a link to the official instructions that you are following.

Comment: Please include the output of `systemctl status docker`

Comment: Ok, I just update the question

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Docker is not configured to run with your normal user.

Try to run your curl with sudo:

```
sudo curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

If works, it was a permission problem. If you want to run docker with you normal user, add it to the docker group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker your_user
```

Probably you'll need to restart your machine after this.

Comment: I have tried like that but I get the same error

Comment: @wrrnrtm i suspect that the three warning on the systemctl status might have something to do with the error, but i couldn't find an answer beyond that